# Laravel application .env file parameters to app.yaml for GCloud App Engine and path to root

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Laravel (7.x) application which I have been developing locally and it has the environment variables in the .env file. I want to deploy it to GCloud app engine and I have an app.yaml file ready for it. However, some of the parameters from the .env file are not there in the app.yaml file. Do I need to copy these into it or does the .env file also get uploaded and the App Engine instance uses that as well? If that is the case does one supersede another?

Also one of my parameters has the path to the credentials json file for GCS located in the root folder, what would be the path on App Engine instance for that same file in the root folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the `.env` file should be skipped, since is only for local development. Instead you can use the tag: `env_variables`:

```
env_variables:
  # Put production environment variables here.
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: YOUR_APP_KEY
```

> Replace `YOUR_APP_KEY` in the `app.yaml` file with an application key you generated.

> If you're on Linux or macOS, the following command will automatically update your `app.yaml`:

`sed -i '' "s#YOUR_APP_KEY#$(php artisan key:generate --show --no-ansi)#" app.yaml`

Here you can find a Community Tutorial: [Run Laravel on App Engine flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible), and [Run Laravel on Google App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard).

Comment: Thanks and what about the path to credential json files? How do I define that in the app.yaml?

Comment: I think this might answer your question:  [Passing credentials via env var.](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_variable):
`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"`. There is also an example [`Passing credentials using code`](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code)

Comment: Thanks, but what is the `[PATH]` value for the root of your app engine instance?

Comment: `PATH` is the location of your credentials, in your question should be: >credentials json file for GCS located in the root folder,

Comment: Ok so if I understood correctly the env variables will be as: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:"credentials.json"` in the app.yaml file correct? Sorry I am relatively new to GCP.